# Error in Weka's Gaussian Processes algorithm: Multiplication is only applicable to doubles

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, weka

I have this  dataset I want to apply weka algorithm to it by request an API

```
@RELATION dataset

@ATTRIBUTE timestamp DATE "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"
@ATTRIBUTE action {scale_up}
@ATTRIBUTE duration NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE useful {0,1}

@DATA
"2023-07-05 11:31:18 WAT",scale_up,12,0
"2023-07-05 11:31:17 WAT",scale_up,10,0
"2023-07-05 11:31:16 WAT",scale_up,8,0
"2023-07-05 11:31:15 WAT",scale_up,42,1
"2023-07-05 11:31:14 WAT",scale_up,12,0
"2023-07-05 12:31:13 WAT",scale_up,32,1
```

this is part of code where the problem exist the rest of the code is for loop and it didnt get executed

```
try {
            String pathToWineData = "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\vermeg\\models\\dataset.arff";
            Instances wine = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToWineData)));

            int trainSize = (int) Math.round(wine.numInstances()*0.67);

            int testSize = wine.numInstances()-trainSize;

            Instances train = new Instances (wine,0,trainSize);
            Instances test = new Instances (wine, trainSize,testSize);
            ArrayList<Double> errors = new ArrayList<Double>();

            WekaForecaster forecaster = new WekaForecaster();
            forecaster.setFieldsToForecast("useful");


            if(algorithme.equalsIgnoreCase("Gaussian")){
                forecaster.setBaseForecaster(new GaussianProcesses());
            }
            if(algorithme.equalsIgnoreCase("Linear")){
                forecaster.setBaseForecaster(new LinearRegression());
            }
            if(algorithme.equalsIgnoreCase("Multilayer")){
                forecaster.setBaseForecaster(new MultilayerPerceptron());
            }
            forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setTimeStampField("timestamp");
            forecaster.buildForecaster(wine, System.out);
            forecaster.primeForecaster(wine);

            List<List<NumericPrediction>> forecast = forecaster.forecast(nombre, System.out);
            forecaster.postExecution();
```

and the error show that exactly the error caused because of

```
            forecaster.getTSLagMaker().setTimeStampField("timestamp");
            forecaster.buildForecaster(wine, System.out);
            forecaster.primeForecaster(wine);
```

and this is the error

```
weka.core.expressionlanguage.core.SemanticException: Multiplication is only applicable to doubles!
    at weka.core.expressionlanguage.common.Operators.times(Operators.java:75)
    at weka.core.expressionlanguage.parser.Parser$CUP$Parser$actions.CUP$Parser$do_action_part00000000(Parser.java:556)
    at weka.core.expressionlanguage.parser.Parser$CUP$Parser$actions.CUP$Parser$do_action(Parser.java:720)
    at weka.core.expressionlanguage.parser.Parser.do_action(Parser.java:224)
```

can't figure it out. Any ideas?